# How to remove all input outline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to remove all form inputs outline. Is it possible to remove input outline using jQuery?

I only know how to use CSS like:

```
input, select, textarea, form {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Why not use that CSS? It's what it was designed for.

Comment: Also you forgot `button` there

Comment: JavaScript can be used to change the style of an element, so yes it's possible. If you search for how to style an element with JavaScript, you'll find the answer.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css

Comment: ...and probably a good idea to learn some basic JavaScript before using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// once the page loads
window.onload = function() {
  // set the style for all these elements to outline: none;
  $("input, select, textarea, form").css("outline", "none");
};
```

So once the page loads, all elements' outlines will be set to none.  However, I would suggest using CSS unless there is a specific reason why you want to use jQuery.

And for later appended elements (such as elements that appear after the page loads), you can add this code after the above code:

```
// once an element appears
$("input, select, textarea, form").ready(function() {
  // set the style for all these elements to outline: none;
  $("input, select, textarea, form").css("outline", "none");
});
```

Comment: And if you want to add `button`, like @antyrat mentioned, just change it to say `$("input, select, textarea, form").css("outline", "none");`

Comment: `$("input, select, textarea, form").ready(function(){...})` it doesn't work like that for futur appended elements.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon if he's using a global element query like that it makes no sense why he wouldn't use CSS in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CSS so if you don't have access to the CSS files then you could do this

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">input, select, textarea, form {outline: none;}</style>');
```

This way you don't have to worry about elements that get appended after the page is rendered.

If you use Vinnie's solution you need to run that function after the DOM is loaded and every time you add a new `input, select, textarea, form` element to the DOM, this is why CSS works so well.

Comment: I don't think this is what is being asked for here, since this is the same as using plain CSS.

Comment: @VinnieCaprarola maybe he cant use CSS files for some reason